In unreal engine 5 why do I need to use replication in multiplayer when creating a crouch or prone action but not for regular movement
I'm doing a tutorial on multiplayer and this came up but I don't see any obvious reasons why I need replication for the animations to work for crouching and prone but not for movement and jumping.

Crouching and prone are defined character states without any defaults including animation, swimming is another one.
The default character anim graph wires in the character's default replicated values of speed, isJumping and via object: transform.
Any other states are either not replicated or not tested for by default.
Please remember attribution is required.

Can you explain more on what you mean by "attribution is required"?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

I don't know what you are implying with attribution and the licensing link. Are you saying I need to credit someone with the context of my question?

No, If you are releasing a video, a small credit of some form is required. Usually, a brief shout out, or credit in the description or end credits... To be honest I do not care(and formally release this specific answer to the public domain at the users option), but it is required for any copyright-able  answer used from this site.

I see what you mean. No, this was for my own clarification. The answer is good though, makes sense now. Thanks.
